# Expand and scroll to hidden element

Tags: jquery

I am using this to toggle the display of a div...

```
<script>
jQuery(".trigger").not('.edit .trigger').click(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
jQuery("#target").slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

But I am trying to adapt it so that it not only expands the hidden div, it also scrolls to the expanded div (#target).  So far everything I have tried breaks it completely, any ideas?

I have just tried

```
 <script>
 $element = $('#target');
 $element.hide();
 $('.trigger').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $a = $(this);

 $element.slideToggle(250, function(){
    $(window).scrollTop($a.offset().top);
 });
 });
</script>
```

But I get  $ is not a function

Comment: You should add the code you tried, so we can help you fix that

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error "$ is not a function" try using jQuery() instead of $().

You should define the variables with the word var.

Your scrollTop function scrolls to the .trigger element, not the target.
That would look like this (not tested):

```
 <script>
 var element = jQuery('#target');
 element.hide();
 jQuery('.trigger').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    element.slideToggle(250, function(){
       jQuery(window).scrollTop(element.offset().top);
    });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  It works perfectly.

The only trouble I have now is when the #target div opens, the page automatically scrolls to it which is perfect, but I am now trying to work out if it is possible to hide the #target div again when someone scrolls to 300px from the top of the page.  Again i am drawing a blank... javascript is not my strong point.

Comment: @user2227359 I would say, take a look at the  jQuery(window).scroll() function with jQuery(this).scrollTop() for the scroll position to check the scroll height.